# Is there any way to show remote references with git log?

Tags: git, gerrit, git-log

```
git log --oneline
```

The above command gives me the followed results:

```
5485b34 Modify: something 
ccaf2c4 Modify: another thing
85a87e8 Bug Fix: the other thing
```

But because I'm using gerrit and usually gerrit has it's change number as refs/changes/... format, I want to collect list framed as follows:

```
refs/changes/85/104085/9 Modify: something
refs/changes/33/104033/9 Modify: another thing
refs/changes/83/104183/2 Bug Fix: the other thing
```

I know there is a way to obtain the mapping between commit IDs and remote references by using "git ls-remote". And by using "git ls-remote", I can make a script to obtain the above result. But is there any better and simpler way to obtain the above results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can display references in logs with the `--decorate` option.
But it will only display the local and fetched references so the `refs/changes/x/yyyy/zz` won't be displayed, you have to fetch them first:

```
git config --add remote.origin.fetch refs/changes/*:refs/remotes/gerrit/changes/*
```

Then you will get an output like this:

```
# You can add '--all' to see other references not in the current history
$ git log --oneline --decorate
5485b34 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD, gerrit/changes/85/104085/9) Modify: something 
ccaf2c4 (gerrit/changes/33/104033/9) Modify: another thing
85a87e8 (gerrit/changes/83/104183/2) Bug Fix: the other thing
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I really wanted.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to get the info the way you want but you can get a lot of Gerrit review info doing the following:

1) Configure your repository to get the review info

```
$ git config --add remote.origin.fetch refs/notes/review:refs/notes/review
```

2) After that, every update will bring the review info too

```
$ git fetch

remote: Counting objects: 66, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (66/66)
remote: Total 66 (delta 18), reused 66 (delta 18)
Unpacking objects: 100% (66/66), done.
From https://GERRIT-SERVER/REPO-FULLNAME
* [new ref] refs/notes/review -> refs/notes/review
```

3) To see the review info, add "--notes=review" to your "git log" command

```
$ git log --notes=review

commit a5bc87cb44e5e68154fb8bd3559f9753e1540fd7
Author: AUTHOR
Date: Thu May 8 16:02:16 2017 -0300
COMMIT-MESSAGE
Change-Id: CHANGE-ID
Notes (review):
Verification+1: REVIEWER1
Code-Review+1: REVIEWER2
Code-Review+1: REVIEWER3
Code-Review+2: REVIEWER4
Submitted-by: SUBMITTER
Submitted-at: Fri, 09 May 2017 08:23:28 -0300
Reviewed-on: https://GERRIT-SERVER/CHANGE-NUMBER
Project: REPO-FULLNAME
Branch: refs/heads/BRANCH
```

Answer (score -1):

You can probably get what you want by using `git log --oneline --pretty=format:'you_format_here'`

Take a look at the man page for all the available options : https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats